# msbuild reference assemblies resolve order while building solution with multiple .csproj in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, assembly-resolution

I have a solution with multiple projects and these projects have `nuget` packages installed which are different in version. Looks when solution is rebuild, the version of dll copied to output directory is not deterministic and often I end up with runtime "*file not found*" exception for obvious reason. I will try to over simply the problem with below example :

Let's say `ProjectA` is cossole application and refers `version 1.0.0` of assembly `xyz`.

`ProjectA` also refers to `ProjectB` in same solution via project reference. Now let say `ProjectB` references `version 2.0.0` of assembly `xyz`.

I would like to know when solution is rebuild, is it deterministic which version of `xyz dll` will be copied to output directory ? If no, is there a way to ensure this. I know in that case I need to update config with appropriate binding re direction policy.

Comment: This is supposed to be resolved by MSBuild, it looks at the references and their dependencies and tries to find a solution.  Adding BindingRedirects to the config file as needed to convince the CLR that it might work.  Without a detailed build trace it is just guessing why this did not happen.  Consider linking to a paste-bin to get this question answered.

Comment: @HansPassant : here is [link](https://pastebin.com/im6hdFrC) to paste bin. so it is log for - projectA (console app) refers to ProjectB class library. ProjectB refers to version 8.0.0 of Newtonsoft.json.dll where as ProjectA has version 11.0.0 of Newtonsoft.json.dll. However, my final o/p directory after rebuild have version 11.0.0. Am trying to understand from log if msbuild initially copied version 8.0.0 and then overwrite it with version 11.0.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to know when solution is rebuild, is it deterministic which version of xyz dll will be copied to output directory?

Yes, the `version 1.0.0` of xyz dll will be copied to output directory.

According to the document [Dependency resolution with PackageReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/dependency-resolution#dependency-resolution-with-packagereference):

> When the package graph for an application contains different versions
>   of the same package, **NuGet chooses the package that's closest to the
>   application in the graph and ignores all others**. This behavior allows
>   an application to override any particular package version in the
>   dependency graph.

In you case, the version 1.0.0 of `xyz.dll` is nearer to the `projectA` in the graph, that version will be copied to the output directory.

Then I also created a test package `xyz` with version 1.0.0 and 2.0.0, add those two nuget package to the `projectA` and `projectB`, then `ProjectA` also refers to `ProjectB`, after build, the version 1.0.0 xyz.dll copied to the output directory:

[image]

**Update:**

> Can you check and confirm on the behavior when dll version is
>   different in ProjectA and ProjectB \

To verify this question, I have created a project xyz, generated the version `1.0.0 xyz.dll` and `2.0.0 xyz.dll`, then refers `2.0.0 xyz.dll` to the `project B` and `1.0.0 xyz.dll` to the `project A`, build the solution, got the same result: `1.0.0 xyz.dll` will be copied to the output directory:

[image]

As the above test results, `1.0.0 xyz.dll` will be copied to the output directory. When you got the file not found error, please check if you are invoke the method in version 2.0.0 the xyz.dll.

**Update2:**

> screen shot you showing says file version (but file version is not
>   same as assembly version)

That because I want to be able check the `AssemblyVersion` in the windows explorer more convenient, I change the `AssemblyVersion` and `AssemblyFileVersion` at the same time before gnenerating the different version dll:

Like:

`1.0.0 xyz.dll`:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

`2.0.0xyz.dll`:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("2.0.0.0")]
```

So we just need check the file version instead of assembly version in wondows explorer for more convenient.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks !! But i am not referring to nuget or file version, I am referring to assembly version. But as per your explanation, looks it still will choose deterministic version 1.0.0 of assembly. Can you check and confirm on the behavior when dll version is different in ProjectA and ProjectB \

Comment: @RahulAgarwal, Do you mean reference different version of dll file directly to Project A and Project B?

Comment: yes, i think i kind of miscommunicated in OP by saying different nuget version. But i assumed people will take different nuget package version will have different assembly version as well.

Comment: @RahulAgarwal, I have test it with different version of dll file directly to Project A and Project B, but got the same result. Check my updated answer for details.

Comment: Thanks !! Is there any documentation which says how msbuild resolves assembly reference graph. Is "close to"  concept applicable in that case also. Also just for FYI..screen shot you showing says file version (but file version is not same as assembly version)

Comment: @RahulAgarwal, I have not found the official document about this for C# programming, but just as you said, nuget package should have the same behavior as C#. In the nuget official document, it declare that using the "close to" assembly. And some other answer also support this opinion: **If any kind of element from a dependency is used directly from the project where the assembly is referenced, that reference will be copied.** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26163368/is-copy-local-transitive-for-project-references/26163944#26163944

Comment: @RahulAgarwal, for your second question "screen shot you showing says file version (but file version is not same as assembly version)", I explained the reason in my update2 answer, you can check it for more details.

Comment: Thanks, i did not noticed update. Also msbuild refers to `ResolveAssemblyReference Task`  [msdn link here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ad3f294.aspx) to resolve these references.

Comment: @RahulAgarwal, Yes, I also found that document, but it only provide us the task, not much more explanation the "close to".  But as we test the "close to" should be correct, what is your question now?

Comment: I deeply appreciate you guys share these ideas, I also confused about such thing before, after read, I have another question: if say A -> B, and A ->C, B,C is at the same level to project A, if B, C both reference an assmebly D which has different version: B reference D on ver 1.0 and C reference D on ver 2.0, which version D assembly is copied under A's bin folder after build?